# Why is the weight vector in PLS constrained to be of unit length?

Tags: pca, intuition, partial-least-squares

In the SIMPLS formulation of partial least squares (PLS) regression, the weights are constrained to have length of 1,

$$r_a^Tr_a = 1,$$ where $a$ represents a latent component (from $1$ to $A$). This is from the original definition by de Jong (1993).

As the `plsgenomics` package says in the help for the `pls.regression` function:

> In the original definition of SIMPLS by de Jong (1993), the weight
>       vectors have length 1. If the weight vectors are standardized to have
>       length 1, they satisfy a simple optimality criterion (de Jong, 1993).

I read de Jong's paper and he says:

> For the development of the theory and algorithm of SIMPLS it was
>       convenient to choose normalized weight vectors $r_a$. This choice, 
>       however, is in no way essential.

My question is this. Can anyone give me an intuition for what effect constraining the length of the weight vector has on the algorithm?

**References:**

- de Jong, S. [SIMPLS: an Alternative Approach To Partial Least-Squares Regression](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016974399385002X). Chemom. Intell. Lab. Syst. 18, 251–263 (1993).

Comment: Take something simpler than PLS, e.g. PCA. Do you know why eigenvectors in PCA are constrained to unit length?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.  I don't know why in this simpler case either.

Comment: Then see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117695.

Comment: Great @amoeba.  If you post this link as an answer I will accept it (or if you want to close this as duplicated that's ok too). Thanks!

Comment: @amoeba, I tried to upvote but I'm so new that I can't (you need 15 reputation first).  Probably shouldn't have closed as a duplicate - my fault.  You'll get my upvote once I can ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is instructive to consider a simpler case of PCA first.

Given data matrix $\mathbf X$, PCA finds a direction $\mathbf w$ such that the variance of the projection is maximized: $$\mathbf w = \mathrm{argmax}\; \mathrm{Var}(\mathbf X \mathbf w).$$ To be able to search for the optimal direction, one needs to fix the length of $\mathbf w$, otherwise the variance can be made arbitrarily large by increasing its length. Constraining the length of $\mathbf w$ to any number $\alpha$ would work fine, but it is particularly convenient to choose $\|\mathbf w\|=1$, because only then is $\mathbf X \mathbf w$ a projection on the *direction* of $\mathbf w$.

See this thread for more details: [Why is the eigenvector in PCA taken to be unit norm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117695)

Now turning to PLS, we will see that the situation is exactly the same. Given data matrix $\mathbf X$ and a response variable $\mathbf y$, PLS looks for a direction $\mathbf w$ such that the covariance of $\mathbf y$ and the projection of $\mathbf X$ onto $\mathbf w$ is maximized: $$\mathbf w = \mathrm{argmax}\; \mathrm{Cov}(\mathbf X \mathbf w, \mathbf y).$$ Again, for this formulation to make sense, one needs to fix the length of $\mathbf w$ and it is convenient to fix it to $1$.