# PCA returns the same pair of principal axes for completely different 2D datasets

Tags: pca

I noticed a (seemingly) weird behavior while using sklearn's [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA) on 2D [standardized](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) datasets: I kept getting the same principal axes: $\pm\left(\begin{gathered}\sqrt{0.5}\\
\sqrt{0.5}
\end{gathered}
\right)$ and $\pm\left(\begin{gathered}\sqrt{0.5}\\
-\sqrt{0.5}
\end{gathered}
\right)$ (i.e. the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$), even when I significantly changed the dataset.

Just to be sure, I wrote a short script that demonstrates this behavior:
(The script creates nonsense datasets from different distributions, and standardizes and performs PCA on each dataset.)

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

dists_funcs = [np.random.chisquare, np.random.exponential, np.random.power,
               np.random.standard_gamma, np.random.weibull, np.random.rayleigh,
               np.random.pareto, np.random.poisson, np.random.standard_t] 
sqrt_of_half = 0.5 ** 0.5
n = 1000

for i, dist_func1 in enumerate(dists_funcs[:-1]):
    dist_func2 = dists_funcs[i + 1]
    X = np.array([(a, a * dist_func2(i + 2)) for a in dist_func1(i + 3, n)])
    pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA(n_components=2))
    pipe.fit(X)
    pca = pipe.named_steps['pca']
    for principal_axe in pca.components_:
        for z in principal_axe:
            if abs(abs(z) - sqrt_of_half) > 1e-10:
                print(f'got {principal_axe} in {i}')
print('done')
```

Is this behavior guaranteed? Is there an intuitive explanation for it?

Comment: This isn't weird: see the figure just above the "Application" heading I posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71260/what-is-the-intuition-behind-conditional-gaussian-distributions/71303#.  When you standardize the dataset, there is only one more parameter determined by its first and second moments--the correlation coefficient--which leaves no freedom for anything else (such as the direction of a principal axis) to vary.  The sole exception is the case of zero correlation, where the principal axes are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation for the described behavior and when it would happen, though I don't find it intuitive.

First, the $2$ principal axes are orthonormal eigenvectors of the covariance matrix $C$. This is explained and proved in an [answer by amoeba](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/219344/215801).

Thus, the behavior is guaranteed iff each eigenvector of the covariance matrix is given by $t\left(\begin{gathered}1\\
1
\end{gathered}
\right)$ or $t\left(\begin{gathered}1\\
-1
\end{gathered}
\right)$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$.

Since the dataset given to PCA in this case is standardized, the variance of both features (aka variables) is $1$. As $C$ [is symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Basic_properties), there exists an $a$ such that $C=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & a\\
a & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$.

If $a=0$ (i.e. the variables are uncorrelated), then $C=I$. Thus, $\left(\begin{gathered}1\\
0
\end{gathered}
\right)$ and $\left(\begin{gathered}0\\
1
\end{gathered}
\right)$ are eigenvectors, and the behavior is not guaranteed.

Otherwise, $a\not=0$. Let's [find the eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_the_characteristic_polynomial) of $C$: $$\begin{gathered}\left|C-\lambda I\right|=0\\\left|\left(\begin{matrix}1-\lambda & a\\
a & 1-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right)\right|=0\\
\left(1-\lambda\right)^{2}-a^{2}=0\\
\left(1-\lambda+a\right)\left(1-\lambda-a\right)=0\\
\lambda=1+a\,,\,1-a
\end{gathered}$$

So by definition, $\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)$ is an eigenvector of $C$ iff $\left[C\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)=(1+a)\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)\text{ or }C\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)=(1-a)\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)\right]$, which (by doing the algebra) holds iff $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

In other words, $\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)$ is an eigenvector of $C$ iff $\left(\begin{gathered}x\\
y
\end{gathered}
\right)$ is given by $t\left(\begin{gathered}1\\
1
\end{gathered}
\right)$ or $t\left(\begin{gathered}1\\
-1
\end{gathered}
\right)$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$.
Therefore, the behavior is guaranteed.

By the same reasoning, we could show that the behavior is guaranteed in any case such that $C=\left(\begin{matrix}b & a\\
a & b
\end{matrix}\right)$ and $a,b\not=0$.
i.e. we would get the behavior also in cases where we only center the dataset, the features aren't uncorrelated, and have the same variance.