# Understanding the decomposed matrices in Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: intuition, svd, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to get some intuition regarding the U and V matrices in SVD ($M=UEV^T$). I think these are orthonormal basis vectors, but I am struggling to get an intuition if they represent anything more than matrix transformations.

For example, in NMF, I understand that the decomposed matrices can be combined as a linear combination of basis vectors in one matrix with weights in the other matrix. In PCA, I understand that the eigenvectors have real significance in representing orthogonal axes of maximal variation, defined by the eigenvalues. But in SVD, I don't see any immediate connection.

Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

In a singular value decomposition, $M$ is not (necessarily) symmetric or even square; it's a transformation from one space ($\mathbb{R}^M$) to another ($\mathbb{R}^n$).

Let's supppose $m>n$. $M$ can be decomposed into a transformation into a convenient basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $U$, then a projection and scaling by $E$ into a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ , then a rotation into the target basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $V^T$.

(Alternatively, for the compact SVD, $U$ is $m\times n$ and includes the projection, and $E$ is just the scaling)

Also, just as in PCA, it's no loss of generality (and is standard) to organise $E$ from largest to smallest singular value, and $U$ and $V$ represent orthogonal axes of maximal variation in the two spaces. There are various efficient algorithms for giving you just the largest few singular values and corresponding vectors (either Lanczos-type or stochastic algorithms)

Comment: "Also, just as in PCA, it's no loss of generality (and is standard) to organise  from largest to smallest singular value, and  and  represent orthogonal axes of maximal variation in the two spaces"
Would you mind elaborating? This isn't immediately obvious to me. In PCA, I saw how this would be the case because of the objective function (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217995/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-how-pca-turns-from-a-geometric-problem-wit), but here I'm not so sure